# How to select 5 distinct rows

Tags: mysql

How do I select 5 rows, 1 for each `site_id`, this is throwing an error

```
SELECT DISTINCT site_id, * 
FROM deal 
WHERE site_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6) 
ORDER BY id 
DESC LIMIT 5
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM deal WHERE site_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5' at line 1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT * 
FROM deal 
WHERE site_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6) 
GROUP BY site_id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Doh!  Duh, I should've thought of this!

Comment: Pretty good. Note that SELECTing columns that aren't in the GROUP_BY is a MYSQL extension, and there's no guarantee about which rows are returned. (So if he wants the one with the maximum ID, there's no guarantee he'll get it.)

Comment: @Ken you're right - if he wants more than just one row, any row for each site id, then your solution is what he needs.

Answer (score 1):

If your table allows duplicate site_ids, and you only need to show one per site_id, then assuming ID is unique

```
SELECT * FROM deal
WHERE id in (
    SELECT max(id) maxid
    FROM deal
    WHERE site_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    GROUP by site_id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

First get one particular deal ids (the maximum one) for each site. (The inner query.)
Then get the full row for each of those deal ids. (The outer query.)

```
SELECT * FROM deal
WHERE id in (
    SELECT max(id) maxid
    FROM deal
    WHERE site_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    GROUP_BY site_id
)
```

You can remove following line if you're really interested in getting one row for each site for all of the sites in the database.

```
     WHERE site_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: @Brent: #1: I'm fixing up cyberkiwi's answer. #2: you gotta pick a specific *one* somehow. #3: I assume that the purpose of `ORDER BY id` in the query posted in the question was to get the maximum id (though from the looks of it, if his query could be made to work, it would actually use `min(id)` instead.)

Comment: Ok, I thought I might have missed something. The original question was a little ambiguous. I suspect that site_id is unique so none of the additional conditions would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify DISTINCT site_id and also include the * wildcard. If you want to specify the distinct site_id, then you need to remove the wildcard and specify the other fields you want to use.

Comment: -1: you've identified the problem. Now can you tell him how to solve it?

Comment: I thought I was pretty specific - If you want to specify the distinct site_id, then you need to remove the wildcard and specify the other fields you want to use. Since I do not know which fields he wants to use I can only give him instructions. Either remove the wildcard, or remove the distinct site_id.

Comment: If he specifies the other fields, then he gets distinct values over all of them (even if the site id is duplicated). It's possible to use `DISTINCT *` in SQL, which gets you all distinct rows, so I suspect the syntax problem is in the `site_id, *` (where `site_id` is already covered by the *)

Comment: Correct, the problem is with distinct site_id, * so one or the other needs to be removed. If site_id is duplicated then it would make sense to use distinct site_id, field_1, field_2. If site_id is unique then he would only need * as in the selected answer.

Comment: @Brent: `distinct site_id, field_1, field_2` will give you multiple copies of the same `site_id` if the same `site_id` has two different `field_1` values. (However, you did state that your assumption is that `site_id` is distinct over the whole table, in which case I can't understand why you need `select distinct` in the first place.)

Comment: Right, I get that distinct site_id will return multiple rows if any of the other additional fields are different. Since the original question did not specify, I answered in general terms that would account for that possibility. My assumption that site_id is unique did not factor in to my answer since that is unknown.